# Framework7: Navigating to a route with different parameters while preserving history

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, html-framework-7

i'm using Framework7 and Vue and the router doesn't load a page with a different parameter.

main.js:

```js
new Vue({
    framework7: {
        root: '#app',
        routes: Routes,
        pushState: true,
        cache: false,
    },
    // ...
```

routes.js

```js
// ...
{
    path: '/gallery/:id',
    component: Gallery
},
// ...
```

left-panel.vue:

```js
// ... 
galleryItemClicked(id) {
    let link = `/gallery/${id}`;
    this.$f7.mainView.router.load({ url: link });
}
// ...
```

The router loads the page only for the first time, but doesn't load it again when I try to load a url with different parameters.

`router.reloadPage(url)` do work, but it doesn't keep the navigation history which is very much needed. It's important to make use of Framework7 history because each page contains lengthy ajax calls, and if I create my own back stack it will cause these ajax calls to be triggered again on back.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into `router.load` options I found the following item:

`pageElement`: HTMLElement of page to load if it is already added to the Pages container manually or by different means/library.

That means I need to add the page using VueJS and then navigate to it using Framework7. So I came with the following solution:

left-panel.vue:

```
// ... 
galleryItemClicked(id) {
    this.$emit('navigate', id);
}
// ...
```

main.vue template:

```
<!-- ... -->
<left-panel @navigate="addGalery"></left-panel>
<!-- ... -->
<f7-views>
    <f7-view id="main-view" navbar-through :dynamic-navbar="true" main>
        <f7-pages>
            <gallery v-for="galleryId in galleries 
                     :id="galleryId" 
                     :key="id"></gallery>
<!-- ... -->
```

main.vue script:

```
// ...
data() {
    return {
        // ...
        galleries: []
    };
},
methods: {
    // ...
    addGalery(id) {
        this.galleries.push(id);
    },
}
```

gallery.vue template

```
<template>
<f7-page ref="galleryElement">
    <!-- ... -->
</f7-page>
</template>
```

gallery.vue script

```
// ...
mounted() {
    this.$f7.mainView.router.load({ pageElement: this.$refs.galleryElement.$el });
},
// ...
```